# How are black hole masses calculated from gravitational waves?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, astrophysics, gravitational-waves, ligo

I would like to know what data is used from gravitational wave detections to calculate black hole masses and how. 
Also, what else can you deduce from gravitational wave detections? What was the exact difference between the detection of the black hole mergers and the one of neutron star collision?

I am writing an extended essay on this (4000 words), and it would be very helpful. Many thanks.